# Unable to record on pre-prod url using HTTP Test Script recorder

Tags: jmeter

The webpage breaks when using recording in JMeter3.0. It's working when we try using JMeter2.13 version.
I am using Firefox 47 version with Jmeter 2.13 on Windows 7. 
I started the Test script recorder and entered the URL in Firefox browser (manual proxy config are done correctly in Firefox browser)
The page do not load correctly and gives error
When I see "View Result Tree" in workbench it shows following error various times

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert:  unrecognized_name
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.handshakeAlert(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:553)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:412)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.LazySchemeSocketFactory.connectSocket(LazySchemeSocketFactory.java:97)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:179)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:328)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.open(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:612)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:447)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:619)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:379)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1135)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:465)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:410)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:241)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

The options are in:

- Try upgrading to [JMeter 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-key-things-you-need-know-about-jmeter-30) and [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre8-downloads-2133154.html), you seem to be suffering from a Java bug [JDK-7177232](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7177232)
- If for some reason you cannot perform the upgrade you can try working it around by  setting `jsse.enableSNIExtension` system property to `false`. You can do it in 2 ways:

  1. Add the next line to *system.properties* file (lives in JMeter's "bin" folder"

     ```
     jsse.enableSNIExtension=false
     ```

     JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up
  2. Pass the property via `-D` command-line argument like:

     ```
     jmeter -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false -n -t ....
     ```